# Returning position of any character in the text

Tags: c, string

The program is designed to return the position of the character in the table s2, in the text of Table S1. In case of failure it will a return -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RANGE 10

int any(char [], char []);

int main()
{
    char s1[RANGE];
    char s2[RANGE];
    int i,j;
    while( (s1[i]=getchar()) != EOF);
    while( (s2[j]=getchar()) != EOF);
    printf("%d", any(s1, s2));
 }

 int any(char s1[], char s2[])
 {
 int i,j;

 for(i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++)
    for(j=0;s2[j]!='\0';j++)
    {
        // for debug
        printf("\n%s", s1[i]);
        printf("\n%s", s2[j]);
        //
        if(s1[i]==s2[j])
            return i;
    }
 return -1;
 }
```

It seems to me that the problem occurs when comparing the characters in the tables.

In this case, programme should return -1:
[image]

Comment: what problem? nice program. what's your question?

Comment: They are called arrays, not tables!

Comment: i and j are not initialized in main. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code has the following problems:

(1) Variables *i* and *j* are uninitialized in the code, potentially causing a crash:

```
int i,j;
while( (s1[i]=getchar()) != EOF);
while( (s2[j]=getchar()) != EOF);
```

(2) The code also needs to increment the values of *i* and *j* as input is being read.  Failing to do so will cause all input to be written to s1[0] / s2[0]:

```
while( (s1[i]=getchar()) != EOF);
while( (s2[j]=getchar()) != EOF);
```

(3) The terminating ^Z characters should be removed from *s1* / *s2* (you might also want to remove the 0x0A (line feed)).

(4) The debug statements are outputting *characters*, not *strings*, so the printf() format string should be "\n%c", not "\n%s".

Cleaning up your code gives the following working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define RANGE 10

int any(char [], char []);

int main()
{
char s1[RANGE];
char s2[RANGE];
int i,j;

i = j = 0;

while( (s1[i++]=getchar()) != EOF);
s1[i-2] = 0;
while( (s2[j++]=getchar()) != EOF);
s2[j-2] = 0;

printf("%d", any(s1, s2));
}

int any(char s1[], char s2[])
{
int i,j;

for(i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++)
for(j=0;s2[j]!='\0';j++)
{
    // for debug
    printf("\n%c", s1[i]);
    printf("\n%c", s2[j]);
    //
    if(s1[i]==s2[j])
        return i;
}
return -1;
}
```

The output for 'aaaa^Z' / 'bbbb^Z' is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
// for debug
printf("\n%s", s1[i]);
printf("\n%s", s2[j]);
```

%s signifies that the argument is a string (aka char*) but you are actually passing just a char.
Try this:

```
// for debug
printf("\n%c", s1[i]);
printf("\n%c", s2[j]);
```